# IndexError: too many indices for array in numpy

Tags: numpy

I'm trying some exercise.
I looked for this problem before, but didn't find one for my problem.

This code seems to work with trainX, but not with trainY.
I have 1672 data for trainY in 1D for one neuron output.

```
   batch_dim = trainX.shape[0]
   input_dim = windowSize
   hidden_dim = 6
   output_dim = 1
```

O: batch_dim=1 with value "1672"

```
    X = trainX[index:index+batch_dim,:]
    Y = trainY[index:index+batch_dim,:]
    index = index+batch_dim
```

The problem seems to be in the dimension. So I try to reshape it

```
    Y = np.reshape(trainY[index:index+batch_dim,:],-1,1)
```

but it doesn't solve anything. The output still work, but error still there.
I just wanted the error to go away.

The variable size output:

```
batch_dim = 1 (value = 1672)
index = 1 (value = 0)
X : (1672,3)
Y : (1672,)
```

> > > Y = trainY[index:index+batch_dim,:]

IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: If `trainY` is 1d, then you have to use `trainY[index:index+batch_dim]`.  That is, omit the trailing `:`.  You can only have one indexing expression per dimension.  For a 2d array, you can omit the trailing `:` - that's added automatically as needed.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much